# Removing any duplicate characters in a string

Tags: c, strings

I have piece of code in C which removes any duplicate characters in a string.  But I am doing it in two loops and would like it to optimize it to one loop.

```
void removeDuplicates(char* ptr)
{
    int end = 1;
    int length = strlen(ptr);
    int current;
    int i;
    current = 1;

    for(end=1; end<length; end++)
    {
        for(i=0; i<end; i++)
        {
            if(ptr[end] == ptr[i])
            break;
        }

        if(i == end)
        {
            ptr[current] = ptr[i];
            current++;
        }
    }

    ptr[current] = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char str[256] = {0,};
    gets(str);
    removeDuplicates(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets()` even in test code.  Forget it exists; use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Remove Duplicates:  (Re-Write Ant's code so it is readable).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removeDuplicates(char* ptr);

void removeDuplicates(char* ptr) 
{
    char seen[UCHAR_MAX+1] = {0};

                              //
                              // Smallest data type is a char (unless you want to bit
                              // twiddle, and that has been shown to be not worth it
                              // see the complaints about std::vector<bool> in C++).
                              // 256 bytes is not much.
                              // 
                              // By using char as they type it prevents all the complex
                              // multiplication/division an bit twiddling that Ant was doing.

    unsigned char* source = (unsigned char*)ptr;
    unsigned char* dest   = (unsigned char*)ptr;
    unsigned char  next;

    do
    {
        next  = *source;       // Get next character.
        if (!seen[next])       // Only enter the `if block` if we have not seen it.
        {
            seen[next] = 1;    // Mark it as seen
            *dest = next;      // Move it to destination.
                               // Note: source will change faster than dest when we
                               //       start seeing dupes, this acts as the copy back
                               //       over the duplicates.
            ++dest;
        }
        ++source;
    }
    while (next != '\0');      // Once we have copied the null terminator quit.
}
```

Comment: That's about 100x more readable, but about 100x less fun... ;)  If you're making assumptions about the size of a char you should be able to get away with `char seen[127]`.  ASCII is only 7-bit.

Comment: No. Its 50x less fun. Still lots of fun left.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should turn out to be faster and more efficient:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removeDuplicates(char* ptr);

void removeDuplicates(char* ptr) {
    int seen[(sizeof(char) << 8) / (sizeof(int) * 8)] = {0,};

    char* source = ptr;
    char* dest = ptr;

    while (*source != '\0') {

        int destIndex = (*source) / (sizeof(int) * 8);
        int destBit = 1 << (*source) % (sizeof(int) * 8);

        if (!(seen[destIndex] & destBit)) {
            *dest = *source;
            ++dest;

            seen[destIndex] |= destBit;
        }

        ++source;
    }

    *dest = '\0';
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char str[256] = {0,};
    gets(str);
    removeDuplicates(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

It uses an array of ints as an array of booleans, each of which indicates whether a character has been seen.  It eliminates the `strlen()` call (which iterates over the entire string) and replaces it with a NULL check.  It uses two pointers into the string, `source` and `dest`, which track the current read location (iterating over the original string) and the current write location (the destination for in-place copying of the next non-duplicate character).

Comment: Sorry you deserve the credit here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're optimizing for time, you could waste some memory and use an array of length `sizeof(char)` -- let's call it `seen` -- initialized with zeros.

In the loop you'd a few things:

1. if the `seen` count is greater than zero, increment an `offset` variable (the value of this offset is equal to how many duplicates of all characters have been found so far)
2. copy the current character to a new position `offset` characters behind, if it was not previously seen -- meaning, if `seen[current_char]` is zero (possibly only if offset is non-zero, otherwise "from" and "to" position are the same)
3. Increment `seen[current_char]` at the end of the loop

Note that `current_char` is really the value of the character, not the index of the character in the input string.